# How to get a pointer to color button

Tags: c++, mfc, color-picker

I have a color button on toolbar, it was created in CMainFrame, how can I get a pointer to the color button which is **CMFCColorMenuButton** derived class from View, like the code below(part of MSOffice2007Demo Sample)? :

```
CMFCRibbonBar* pRibbon = ((CMainFrame*) GetTopLevelFrame())->GetRibbonBar();
ASSERT_VALID(pRibbon);

CMFCRibbonColorButton* pFontColorBtn = DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST(CMFCRibbonColorButton, pRibbon->FindByID(ID_FONT_COLOR));
```

Comment: You're asking two questions. The question in your title is answered in the code you posted. The second question, how to use a pointer, is fairly unspecific. It's a pointer. You use it like any other pointer in C/C++.

Comment: in MSOffice2007Demo Sample its application has the ribbon bar so you can get CMFCRibbonColorButton by  GetRibbonBar(), but my testing application has it as a toolbar button which derived from CMFCColorMenuButton class, so I cannot get a pointer to CMFCColorMenuButton by using FindByID(), my question is that how can I get a pointer to CMFCColorMenuButton on toolbar by using DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST function, or any ideas, plz? @IInspectable, sorry to make you misunderstanded.

Comment: Start by reading through [Control Bars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3d85fetk.aspx). The procedure is the same: Get a pointer to your `CMainFrame`, call [`CFrameWnd::GetControlBar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsy295wy.aspx) to get the toolbar and use [`CToolBar::GetItemID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7bhbdsb.aspx) to retrieve your button's ID. You're ready to perform the final lookup. Most importantly: Learn the Windows API first, or your MFC adventures will not be successful.

Comment: CMFCToolBar* pToolbar = ((CMainFrame*) GetTopLevelFrame())->GetControlBar(IDR_MAINFRAME_256);  /*error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'CControlBar *' to 'CMFCToolBar *' */   /*...but if I change code to "CControlBar* pToolbar =...same code.." an error will occured in the next line*/  CMFCColorMenuButton* pFontColorBtn = DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST (CMFCColorMenuButton, pToolbar->GetItemID(ID_CHAR_COLOR)); /*error C2039: 'GetItemID' : is not a member of 'CControlBar'*/

Comment: You are trying to learn the Windows API, MFC, and C++, all at the same time. You should consider taking a step back and at the very least get up to speed with one of them, C++ preferably.

Comment: Yes, according to the colorbutton I really stunned, but I wonder why you told me to use CFrameWnd::GetControlBar since it will return as CControlBar, then how can I use GetItemID since it is a CToolBar member, at last, even you can use GetItemID how can you get CMFCColorMenuButton since it will just return the command ID. Becuase I really don't know, and have been reading MSDN for times, but failed just for CMFCColorMenuButton, if you really know, wouldn't you please give me a sample?

Comment: `CToolBar` **is** a `CControlBar`. It is explained in the Control Bars introduction I linked to above. Casting is required. To understand why you will have to understand how MFC models relationships among related Windows controls. To understand why it is implemented the way it is you will have to understand Windows controls as exposed through the Windows API. MFC will not make **any** sense unless you know the Windows API and C++.

Comment: You're right, but sorry I forgot to tell you one thing that I'm using is an CMFCToolbar not CToolBar so a CControlBar may be able to use as an initialize value to CToolBar, but not to CMFCToolbar, with this it caused an error I replied in the 4th comment. Moreover my CMainFrame is an MDI derived from CMDIFrameWndEx class that is it maybe another one reason to fail, anyway, I will do more research to find out as your advice, thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process to access button controls in a toolbar requires a number of steps to navigate to the control in question. The following list illustrates this:

1. Get a pointer to the frame window hosting the toolbar.
2. Get a pointer to the toolbar control.
3. *[optional]* Get the button index for a specific command ID.
4. Get a pointer to the button at the specified index.
5. Convert the base class button type to derived class.

   ```
   // Get pointer to mainframe window
   CMainFrame* pFrameWnd = DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST( CMainFrame, AfxGetMainWnd() );

   // Get pointer to the toolbar
   CBasePane* pPane = pFrameWnd->GetPane( AFX_IDW_TOOLBAR );
   CMFCToolBar* pToolBar = DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST( CMFCToolBar, pPane );

   // Find button index for command ID
   int index = pToolBar->CommandToIndex( ID_COLOR_PICKER );

   // Retrieve button
   CMFCToolBarButton* pButton = pToolBar->GetButton( index );

   // Convert button to appropriate type
   CMFCColorMenuButton* pColorButton = DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST( CMFCColorMenuButton,
                                                         pButton );
   ```

A few notes on the implementation:

Error handling has been omitted for brevity. Whenever there is a `DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST` the return value can be `NULL` and has to be checked. Likewise, the call to `CommandToIndex` can fail and requires error handling.

`DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST` is similar to a C++ `dynamic_cast` in that it evaluates whether a runtime type can be converted to another type. While not all Windows control relationships can be modeled as a C++ class hierarchy, MFC provides its own conversion tool: `DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST`.

The ID passed to the call to `CommandToIndex` is the command ID assigned to the `CMFCColorMenuButton` either through a resource script or at runtime, depending on how the control is created.

Comment: It's done here, I will remembered this class as long as I can do a programming, Mr.IInspectable, very thx!